# Angularjs: Pass calendar value from directive to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this device reservation system and it has reservation form which includes field with a pop up calendar. Because I have this calendar pop-up inside a ng-repeat I created a directive for it so it would work.

My problem however is that I have not been able to pass the calendar value from directive to my controller when I save the reservation.

How should I do it?

Here is the save function:

```js
$scope.Start = "";
$scope.saveReservation = function (newReservation, equipment) {
                $scope.$emit('WORKING', true);
                newReservation.EquipmentID = equipment.ID;
                newReservation.StartDate = $scope.Start;

                reservationService.addNew(newReservation)
                       .then(function (response) {
                           $scope.showReservationForm = false;
                           reservationService.getAll()
                             .then(function (response) {
                                 $scope.reservations = response.d.results;
                                 $scope.$emit('WORKING', false);
                                 alert("Your reservation was succesful.")
                             }, function (reason) {
                                 $scope.$emit('WORKING', false);
                                 alert('You reservation failed because of error ' + reason);
                             });

                       });
            };
```

Here is the directive:

```js
"use strict";
(function () {
    angular.module("App").directive('myRepeatDirective', [
        function () {
            return {

                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    if (scope.$last) {
                        $('.bootstrap-datepicker1').datepicker({
                            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                            autoclose: true
                        });
                        $('#bootstrap-datepicker1').on('change', function () {

                            scope.Start = $('#bootstrap-datepicker1').val()
                        });
                        $('.bootstrap-datepicker2').datepicker({
                            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                            autoclose: true
                        });
                        $('#bootstrap-datepicker2').on('change', function () {
                            scope.End = $('#bootstrap-datepicker2').val()
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
        }])
})();
```

And here is the input:

```html
<input style="width: 200px;" type="text" class="bootstrap-datepicker1" id="bootstrap-datepicker1" data-ng-model="Start" placeholder=" dd.mm.yyyy" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scope.$apply to let angular know that value changed outside of angular scope. Else angular doesn't know that value changed.

```
$('#bootstrap-datepicker1').on('change', function () {
   scope.$apply(function(){
       scope.Start = $('#bootstrap-datepicker1').val()
   }) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a 'scope' property on directives definition object.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Also you may find this usefull

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 0):

From your directive, inject `$rootScope` and do a broadcast when you want to pass the data:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("calendarValue", {value: new Date(), foo: "bar"});
```

Now, in your controller, get the value where you want to receive:

```
$scope.$on("calendarValue", function(e, data) {
    console.log(data.foo === "bar");
    $scope.selectedValue = data.value;
});
```